# Formula field doesn't retain old values in the trigger

Tags: trigger, formula, formula-field

I have **scenario 1** - A formula field on Account (custom_type__c) which references the Contact's email as - `Primary_Contact__r.Email` Whenever Primary Contact's email id is changed , Custom Type is updated on Account, which fires account trigger. However, Trigger.Old doesn't retain the old values.
Example- If Primary Contact's email id is abc@xyz.com , Custom Type on Account-abc@xyz.com. Now, email id of Primary Contact's is updated to def@xyz.com , so Custom Type on Account0 def@xyz.com , which fires account trigger. When I print below-

`System.debug('In After Update NEW ' + a.custom_type__c);
 System.debug('In After Update Old ' + Trigger.OldMap.get(a.Id).custom_type__c)`

Both the above statements print-def@xyz.com . **1)Why Trigger.OldMap() doesn't retain the old values?**

I have **scenario 2**- I have changed the reference of the same formula field(custom_type__c) to the account name.Now Custom_Type__c = Name (Refers name of the account), in this case Trigger.OldMap retains the old values of the name.**Why does it retain in scenario 2 but not in scenario 1?**

Comment: I don't think Scenario 1's `custom_type__c` is a formula field. Changes to the values of formula fields do not fire triggers. Is this value updated by a trigger, or perhaps a workflow rule or process?

Comment: In Scenario 1, custom_type__c = Primary_Contact__r.Email  ,is a formula field. Primary Contact is lookup to contact , on account. I update email id on Primary Contact manually , which in turn updates custom type with the new value, and trigger on account fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. In Account trigger only changes to Account trigger Context records can be checked.

Therefore, if you want to handle changes for Primary_Contact fields, please consider writing code in `Contact trigger` (presumably Primary_Contact__c is a lookup to Contact).

**Explanation:**

**Scenario 1:**

1. Contact Record is updated.
2. Contact triggers are run.
3. Contact record changes are committed.
4. Account trigger is triggered. Here old values for the Contact are not present.

**Scenario 2:**

1. Account record is updated.
2. Account trigger is run. Old values for the formula are present because it references Account fields.
3. Account record changes are committed

Comment: Yes. It makes sense.